# Stream events to potentially slow clients

Tags: go, channel

Given a (infinite) stream of events, a server program must stream the events to several clients. For example:

```
for _, event := range events {
  for _, client := range clients {
    client.write(event) // blocking operation
  }
}
```

However, if a client is slow, it can throttle the other clients. Therefore, for each client, we can add a channel (and a client specific goroutine consuming that channel):

```
for _, event := range events {
  for _, client := range clients {
    client.writer <- event // writer channel is consumed by a per-client go routine
  }
}
```

As long as the buffered channel is not full, this works. However, if the channel gets full, it'll block again. I can think of the following options:

- Drop the event on channel full, close the channel, force the client to reconnect. This requires re-negotiating the channel position, or a complete re-stream. The force reset will potentially waste resources, making the slow client even slower
- Add a channel that goes the other way, make the client signal the server that it is ready to receive. This requires the server to keep a track of stream positions for each client (perhaps that is not too bad?). It seems to have a bit more sync than necessary in the nominal (not-slow) case, increasing latency.

Something else? What's the idiomatic `go` way to do this?

**EDIT**: Here's a simple, good looking, but broken solution: track the stream position in the client object, and send the outstanding events:

```
for _, event := range events {
  persisted_events = append(persisted_events, event)
  for _, client := range clients {
    for _, event := range persisted_events[client.last_event:] {
      select {
      case client.writer <- event:
        client.last_event++
      default:
        break
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This allows slow clients to catch-up, without starwing the others. It does not require a disconnect. However, it is also broken: if the stream of events stops while a client is catching up, it is possible that the slow client gets stuck - as the main loop if waiting for new events. Adding a ticker that triggers the loop sometimes is not efficient. Requiring the client to notify the main loop that it is now idle is complex, and potentially doubles the number of events.

Comment: See [the gorilla chat example](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/master/examples/chat/hub.go#L46) for an example of the first approach. If the client is still too slow after smoothing out bursts using the buffered channel, the only option is to reduce the amount of data sent to the client.

Comment: @CeriseLimón: funny, I had that example open : ) However, it doesn't re-stream missed events, making slow clients miss parts of the conversation.

Comment: "if a client is slow, it can throttle the other clients. Therefore, for each client, we can add a channel:"  Not to contraindicate channels, but I would correct that to "therefore, for each client, we can add a *goroutine*".  Concurrency is the simplest way to handle simultaneous clients

Comment: @erenon Re-stream is dependent on the details of your application. The general flow is this: client maintains last event id or timestamp.  Client includes this info when connecting. Server queries database for missing events and writes to client.  Server subscribes client for events and begins streaming new events.  If a client is incapable of keeping up with the event stream, then you must find a way to reduce the data sent to the client.

Comment: @DanielFarrell: edited, to make it clear the channel is consumed by a different goroutine.

Comment: @CeriseLimón: I think I understand the generic architecture of the recovery. I'm wondering if the close/reconnect part can be saved, in an idiomatic go way (i.e: channels and goroutines, mostly). I can do it (did it) with C++ using a simple state machine (send if not behind, send snapshot/recovery if behind, when epoll indicates so, etc). But it requires a careful design. So I'm looking for something obviously correct. I understand if it is too much.

Comment: There is not a Go idiom for sending messages to a client faster than the client can accept the messages.

Comment: @PenélopeStevens: yeah, that'd be really surprising. That's why I'm looking for a solution that can send only nearly as fast, as clients can accept. See my edit for a simple (but broken) attempt.

Answer (score 0):

The best setup I found so far:

```
for {
    var event Event = nil
    select {
    case event, ok := <-events:
        if !ok {
            return
        }
        persisted_events = append(persisted_events, event)
    case event <- ticker:
    }

    for _, client := range clients {
        select {
        case client.writer <- persisted_events[client.num_events:]:
            client.num_events = len(persisted_events)
        default:
        }
    }
}
```

This is a slight variation of the broken example in the question. There are two key differences:

- The writer channel takes a slice of events (instead of a single event)
- There's a ticker, that wakes the loop periodically, even if there are no new events

Combined, this achives that even if a slow client catches up right after it misses the last event(s) before a long silent period, the final catching up is only delayed by one period of the ticker, instead of the combination of the ticker period plus the number of events missed. Therefore, reducing the ticker period can cap the tail latency. Not ideal in terms of performance, but simple (in terms of concurrency).